# OpenCV: How do I calculate minimum for a window around a central pixel?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to extract features from an image by calculating the minimum of a given window around an image and subtracting it from the original pixel value.
However that is turning out to be very slow, as I am iterating throughout the picture. Is there any optimised way to do it?

```
    f = np.asarray(img.shape)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            if mask[i][j]==255:
                row,col = i,j
                begin_row = row - 4
                end_row = row + 4
                begin_col = col - 4
                end_col = col + 4
                if begin_row < 0:
                    begin_row = 0
                if begin_col < 0:
                    begin_col = 0
                if end_col > img.shape[1]:
                    end_col = img.shape[1]
                if end_row > img.shape[0]:
                    end_row = img.shape[0]
                window = img[begin_row:end_row, begin_col:end_col]
                curr = img.item(row, col)
                f.itemset((row, col), curr - window.min())
```

Comment: use `cv2.minMaxLoc` with your mask as input mask parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your goal correctly:

- Input image `I`
- for every pixel `p` in `I` subtract the minimum of the surrounding windows (including the original pixel)

You could then use the morphological filter `erode` which acts like a minimum filter:

```
I_new(p) = I(p) - erode(I, p, window)
```

where you'd parameterize `erode` to have the correct window size and anchor.

As for an actual implementation, you could use the python version of `opencv` with [its `erode` function](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#erode).It is fast since it's implemented in C++/C. It could look like so (untested):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('path/to/image.jpg')

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)
dst = img - cv2.erode(img,kernel)
```

Most importantly: Avoid looping through image arrays with python loops - this can always only be slow.

Comment: I don't want the mean of the window, I want the minimum value
`I_new(p) = I(p) - min(I, p, window)`

Comment: My bad, had written mean instead of minimum in question description.

Comment: Indranil Dutta, I've changed the sample to `erode` since this acts like a minimum filter